# SharePoint 2019 connected lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-lists

I have two custom lists in my SharePoint as per the below image. The first list is dynamic, meaning that new items may be added every day. The second list will be static, meaning that i will have a column for each week of the year and as items I will have 6-7 users. No more items will be added to this list.

I need to find a way to fill in the cell F4 with the total charge for User1 in W1 and so on for all the other users and weeks. So in this case, the cell F4 should lookup in the list1, take all the lines where the user is User1 and the week is W1 and sum the charge, so the result should be 3.

Ideally, the result should be a percentage where 1 = 20% and 5 = 100%.

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: That doesn't appear to be SharePoint; it appears to be Excel.

Comment: The Screenshot is from excel. I have created two excel lists just to present you the context. The Idea is to transpose these two list in Sharepoint and match the fill in criterias as described in the problem statement.

Comment: You probably need to use what's called a Lookup Column. You would probably get better responses if you asked this on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com, instead. Be sure to read their [tour](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour) first, though.